# Set Prometheus Counter value to 0

Tags: prometheus

I want to set Prometheus Counter value to 0 when the server restarts in a manner similar to,

```
private static final Gauge SERVER_UP = Gauge.build(MetricConstants.SERVER_UP, "Server status").labelNames(labels).register();
Gauge gauge = (Gauge) map.get(SERVER_UP);
gauge.labels(serviceName, serviceType).set(0);
```

How can this be done with Counter in Prometheus?

Comment: Why you need to set to 0 if you are creating it from scratch? The initial value is 0, no?

Comment: I want the request count to set to 0 intentionally when the server restarts. As per https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work , "Any time a counter appears to decrease it'll be treated as though there was a reset to 0 right after the first data point."

Comment: So if you want a counter, why are you using a Gauge? Did you try counter class instead? Check this nice link. https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/prometheus-counters/

Comment: I used a Counter. I asked whether there's a similar method in Counter class similar to set(0) in Gauge Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/issues/63) out. tl;dr; counter is not intended to decrease its value, therefore there are some valid uses cases that were under discussion in this thread.

Their recommendation is to unregister the counter and build a new one as a workaround.